# How to remove a file after it has been loop through-Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove a file after I looped through the data in that file. It delete the file when it comes through the first time but when I try to loop the second time it can't open my file.

Error: No such file or directory: C:\***\***\****\*****\\NEWHIRES_MMDDYYYY20210128 (4).CSV'

```
sql = ("select *  from tblTalentReef")
mycursor.execute(sql)

export_rows = mycursor.fetchall() or []

for export_rec in export_rows:
    pa_compid = export_rec['pa_compid']
    pcompany = export_rec['compcode']
    filename = export_rec['filename']
    strFname = export_rec['fname']
    strLname = export_rec['lname']

    strThisFileName = filename
    strFileList =  strThisFileName + chr(10)

    strFileName = r"C:\****\****\*****\******\\" + strThisFileName
    strSavedFileName = r"C:\*****\****\*****\******\processed\\" + strThisFileName


    #Copy File to Destination
    dest = shutil.copyfile(strFileName,strSavedFileName)
    #Delete File
    os.remove(strFileName)
```

I can't put it at the end of the for loop cuz it interfere with my other logic.

Comment: Your use case is not clear. Can you please add further details. In the mean time I will share an example for what I have said.

Answer (score 0):

Add an iterator variable in the start by setting it to zero. During the first run of the loop perform a conditional check on the variable i.e. equals to zero, the condition will be satisfied then delete the file. This should be a multi line if statement statement. After deleting the file increment the iterator variable to one. Inside the conditional check it is comparing to zero, which means the execution won't come again inside to the if block and your file won't be deleted after the first execution.

```
iterator = 1
sql = ("select *  from tblTalentReef")
mycursor.execute(sql)

export_rows = mycursor.fetchall() or []

for export_rec in export_rows:
    pa_compid = export_rec['pa_compid']
    pcompany = export_rec['compcode']
    filename = export_rec['filename']
    strFname = export_rec['fname']
    strLname = export_rec['lname']

    strThisFileName = filename
    strFileList =  strThisFileName + chr(10)

    strFileName = r"C:\****\****\*****\******\\" + strThisFileName
    strSavedFileName = r"C:\*****\****\*****\******\processed\\" + strThisFileName


    #Copy File to Destination
    dest = shutil.copyfile(strFileName,strSavedFileName)
    #Delete the File only for the first time
    if iterator == 0 
        os.remove(strFileName)
        iterator += 1
```

Comment: Thanks about to try

Comment: It wont delete the record @Teja Goud Kandula